# Intersection type with Record<string, never> does not allow property access

Tags: typescript

I was a bit surprised to find out that:

```
type TypeA = Record<string, never> & { propA: string };

const a: TypeA = { // <- Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'
  propA: "lsjdf",
}
```

does not work in TypeScript. I'd love to replace `Record<string, never>` with something that means "empty object" but can't come up with a type that signifies an empty object.

I'd also love to understand why the above does not work.

Comment: What's the goal of intersecting with an empty object? Why not just `type TypeA = { propA: string }`? This already restricts everything aside from `propA`.

Comment: So, I think this is somewhat of a React convenience thing. React provides a type called `PropsWithChildren<P>` and if there are no props to be passed P should be an empty object. For the time being, I created my own helper type `PropsOnlyChildren`.

Comment: Just pass `PropsWithChildren<{}>`

Comment: This would actually be wrong any my linter is rightfully complaining about this. Here's a very good post explaining this: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2063#issuecomment-675156492

Comment: Even though, I don't think it's very problematic in this case since we're using the type in an intersection. But I don't think it's good practice to use `{}` to mean empty object.

Comment: It's not wrong. In most cases, you don't want `{}`, that is correct; I agree with that. However, in this case, `{}` is used correctly and the result is the desired effect. The complaint is an unfortunate side effect of a purposefully greedy linter rule. Assuming it's an intersection under the hood, you can safely ignore it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`never` means never.

`Record<string, never>` means *"`string` type accessors can `never` have a value"* (though `{ [Symbol()]: 'foobar' }` is possible). Your `TypeA` is unusable because it creates a paradox: `propA` is a required `string` property that can `never` exist. The signature is correct, but there is no usable intersection between the types.

There are a few options for "empty":

- `Record<string, never>` is an empty object in the sense that you can't add any string-type accessor properties to it (again, unless you use `Symbol`) **so it will always be empty**.
- `{}` doesn't specify any properties, so any type may be assigned to it because every type satisfies all zero requirements (unless that type can never have accessible properties, i.e. `undefined` and `null`). However, while `const foo: {} = 'bar'` is possible, `{}` doesn't list any properties so there isn't really anything you can do with it without casting/annotations.

Answer (score 1):

u can use  Union Types : |

```js
type TypeA = Record<string, never> | { propA: string };

const a: TypeA = { 
  propA: "lsjdf",
}
```